# HttpServletRequest getting request

Tags: java

I need really help. I have a login.jsp page

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="j_security_check">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="j_username" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="j_password" required="required" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

this is my web.xml

All Pages
             /*
        
        
              MY_User

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>MY_User</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
     <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

In my filter I get the Principal. But somehow when I get into my main Class. The request is gone!

How can I pass my Request to another Java class?

Comment: what do you mean by main class? Is it a servlet?

Comment: Have you added a servlet-mapping to your web.xml to map the url-pattern to your servlet?  For example, something like: <servlet-mapping><servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

**1)** As per your query in comments, you can convert Command.java to a servlet just by extending it with the HttpServlet class. Then you can have access to request and response objects in Command.java class.

**2)** other way to pass request and response objects to your Command.java class is as below:
Let's say you have a servlet `MyServlet` from where you want to call the methods of Command.java class

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{
        Command c =new Command();//object creation depends on your project. e.g you can create it using beans of spring
        c.doSomething(request, response);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Then, your Command class methods should have below parameters:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Command {

    public void doSomething(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("doing something");
    }
}
```

Remember, Servlet request and response are just objects of a simple java class. They does not depend on any api like servlet, you can pass these objects to any java class and their properties will remain same, no matter its servlet or a java class.

Comment: Yes Im using something similar to Spring. Actually it has something to do with a DialogMemory and DialogMachine. The language is called utcj2ee. Its a company specific Framework, that has died 10 years ago. I dont think that this will work with it. I just want to know how to pass my request to this Command.java main class that I have. I cant even store it in the Memory.

Comment: This is not possible, since my MyCommand is already extending the Command class. And making HttpServlet as interface is not possible.